# Rails stub method on initialized ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I want to stub `set_user_tokens` which is executed on the initialized (not saved) ActiveRecord object. This method assigns a token to the `login` object.

```
class AwareLogin < Authenticatable
  def authenticate!
      login = Login.find_or_initialize_for_authentication(params[:login][:email], 'aware')
      class << login
        include AwareAuth
      end

      if login.valid_password?(password) || (set_token = login.id.nil? && aware_response.success?)
        login.set_user_tokens(aware_response) if set_token
        success!(login)
      else
        aware_response.success? ? fail!(:aware_auth) : raise(ActiveRecord::Rollback)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I want to stub `setu_user_tokens` method:

```
    login.set_user_tokens(aware_response) if set_token
```

to receive login ActiveRecord object with attributes of `oauth_tokens` like below:

```
login.oauth_token
=> {"access_token" => return_token,"refresh_token" => nil,"token_expiration" => 1200 }
```

I've tried:

```
      allow_any_instance_of(Login).to receive(:set_user_tokens).with(status: 200, body: { access_token: return_token }.to_json, success?: true).and_return(
        oauth_tokens: {
          "access_token" => return_token,
          "refresh_token" => nil,
          "token_expiration" => 1200 },
      )
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Login does not implement #set_user_tokens

Comment: Not to sound like I am unwilling to help but you implemented my exact recommendations from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941760/rails-ruby-extract-if-block-to-helper-or-guard yet did not accept the answer or even upvote? Slight pettiness aside you should probably use a partial double and stub the method on that instead if possible but we would need more context about your test to determine the best way to go about this

Comment: @engineersmnky hold your horses. I'm accepting all answers only after all my problems are over.

Comment: As I said still willing to help but from an etiquette perspective, that is not the way SO is designed to function. You asked a question your received 1 or more answers that helped you and/or solved your problem, so that question is now complete. Now you have asked a new question with a new problem. All questions and their corresponding answers are independent from one another and should be treated as such by those that ask and those that answer alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be willing to bet your issue is `set_user_tokens` is part of `AwareAuth`.

Since you are only including this module in the eigenclass of the instance (`login`) as part of the `AwareLogin#authenticate!` method, the `Login` class does not implement that method at any point in time.

Is there a reason you are doing it this way rather than just including `AwareAuth` in the `Login` class in the first place?

Either way, while your question appears to lack context for the test itself, if I understand correctly, we should be able to resolve these issues as follows:

```
it 'sets user tokens' do 
  login = Login
    .find_or_initialize_for_authentication('some_email@example.com', 'aware')
    .tap {|l| l.singleton_class.send(:include, AwareAuth) }
  allow(Login).to receive(:find_or_initialize_for_authentication).and_return(login) 
  allow(login).to receive(:set_user_tokens).and_return(
        oauth_tokens: {
          "access_token" => return_token,
          "refresh_token" => nil,
          "token_expiration" => 1200 }
      )
  #perform your action and expectations here
end
```

By using partial doubles you can stub the specific methods you need to without impacting any other functionality of the object itself.